# Sufficient condition for derivative operator

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ denote the vector space of infinitely differentiable functions. Suppose some operator $D$ satisfies the three following conditions:

1. Linearity: $D(\alpha f + \beta g) = \alpha D(f) + \beta D(g) $
2. Product Rule: $D(fg)=fD(g) + D(f)g$
3. $D$ is not trivially zero

If this is the case, does it necessarily follow that $D \propto d/dx ?$ If not, what is a counter example? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: Assuming "proportional" means "proportional by a constant", then $D = \phi d / dx$ is a counterexample for any non-constant infinitely differentiable function $\phi$.